# How to prevent grep from printing the same string multiple times?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

If I grep a file containing the following:

```
These are words
These are words
These are words
These are words
```

...for the word `These`, it will print the string `These are words` four times.

**How can I prevent grep from printing recurring strings more than once?** Otherwise, how can I manipulate the output of grep to remove duplicate lines?

Comment: Should the order of the matches be kept in the output? Otherwise the command John1024 posted will work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Unix philosophy is to have tools that do one thing and do them well.  In this case, `grep` is the tool that selects text from a file.  To find out if there are duplicates, one sorts the text.  To remove the duplicates, one uses the `-u` option to `sort`.  Thus:

```
grep These filename | sort -u
```

`sort` has many options: see `man sort`.  If you want to count duplicates or have a more complicated scheme for determining what is or is not a duplicate, then pipe the sort output to `uniq`:  `grep These filename | sort | uniq` and see `man`uniq` for options.

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep` and an additional switch, if you are looking for only a single string

```
grep -m1 'These' filename
```

---

From `man grep`

```
-m NUM, --max-count=NUM
        Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the input is
        standard input from a regular file, and NUM matching lines are
        output, grep ensures that the standard input is positioned  to
        just  after  the  last matching  line  before exiting, regardless
        of the presence of trailing context lines.  This enables a calling
        process to resume a search.  When grep stops after NUM matching
        lines, it outputs any trailing context lines.  When the -c or
        --count option is also used, grep does not output a count greater
        than NUM.  When the -v or --invert-match option is also used, grep
        stops after outputting NUM non-matching lines.
```

or using `awk` **;)**

```
awk '/These/ {print; exit}' foo
```

Comment: IMHO the most appropriate answer is the -m flag. I suggest you put it at the top of your answer. Very good answer !

Comment: This will not work if you are using a regex - it will stop immediately after the first match, not make sure you get one and only one of each possible match.